# Conditions for a subalgebra to be weakly dense

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a complex, separable Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}(H)$ denote the algebra of bounded linear operators on $H$. Let $A \subset \mathcal{B}(H)$ by a subalgebra. I'm looking for some conditions for $A$ to be weakly (operator) dense in $\mathcal{B}(H)$. I've been looking in books like Arveson, Murphy and Conway and I can't find anything.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: That's fairly vague. What kind of "condition" do you expect?

Comment: For a *-subalgebra $A$ you can use the bicommutant theorem, so $A$ is weakly dense iff every element of $B(H)$ is in $A''$ iff $A' = \mathbb{C}1$. Everything in operator algebras is much more difficult for algebras not closed under $*$.